# mapbox_gl white screen

Tags: flutter, mapbox-gl

I need to use map-box i am sure that all the configurations are fine. but when i run the app the output of the map is like this:

[image]

**The Map Widget is:**

```
MapboxMap(
          accessToken: MAP_BOX_ACCESS_TOKEN,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(34.123456789, 34.123456789),
          ),
          onMapCreated: (_) {},
          onStyleLoadedCallback: () {},
          styleString: MAP_BOX_URL,
        ),
```

I am using the library:
[mapbox_gl](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl)

Comment: There's a known issue on their github issues list. For me it affects Android 12, particularly if the screen resized right before displaying the map. So any resizing of the map container could cause it. I sometimes get around it by adding `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` to my Scaffold widget.

Answer (score 0):

*styleString: MAP_BOX_URL,*
this in your code is not correct, here you have to provide mapbox style url.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).